# What's the "correct" syntax among these for abstract classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abstract-class

Studying the concept of abstract classes, it seems there are different syntaxes to do it, and they all seem to be modern python 3 syntaxes:

One involves putting `metaclass=ABCMeta` in the parenthesis of the class.

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Shape(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id

    @abstractmethod
    def display(self): 
        pass
```

Another one just `ABC`:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def move(self):
        pass
```

And other even requires you dunder methods:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Animal:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def say_something(self): pass
```

It seems all do the same, i prefer the second one since it's the simplest.

Why is one using `ABCMeta` and different syntaxes if all do the same?

Also, why would the first example have an initializer? As far as i know an abstract class should just serve as a blueprint for subclasses, and you cannot even make an instance of it.

I have read they can have non-abstract methods, but without the possibility of instantiate them...it seem fairly pointless.

Comment: "I have read they can have non-abstract methods, but without the possibility of instantiate them...it seem fairly pointless." But you can instantiate subclasses which inherit the concrete implementation from the abstract clasd

Comment: Oh, i completely forgot about that possibility with abstract classes, thank you!

Comment: Anyway, the `ABC` class is basically a stub class that has the `ABCMeta` metaclass. I prefer the explicit use of a metaclass to not have some totally pointless ABC class in the MRO. The last example is Python2 syntax for metaclasses.